# Creating a new directory using Kotlin, Mkdir() doesn't work

Tags: android, kotlin

```
var filename = "blesson.txt"
var wallpaperDirectory = File("/sdcard/Wallpaper")
 wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs()
val outputFile = File(wallpaperDirectory, filename)
val fos = FileOutputStream(outputFile)
```

I am trying to make a new directory on an Android device using Kotlin, but the function `mkdirs()` doesn't work.

```
var filename = "blesson.txt"
var wallpaperDirectory = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().absolutePath)//("/sdcard/Wallpaper")
wall
val outputFile = File(wallpaperDirectory, filename)
val fos = FileOutputStream(outputFile)
```

I have tried this also, it is not making a new directory
Any help is welcome

Comment: When you say "doesn't work", what exactly do you mean? Are you getting an error? Do you just not get the results you want?

Comment: Do you have the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission in your manifest / did you request it at runtime if your target API is 23+?

Comment: Yes I have WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in my manifest file, I am using api 19

Comment: @Todd, as soon as i type mkdirs(), it throws an error

Comment: Can you post the error you're getting?

Comment: OK. What error? Can you edit your question to post the error? Help us out here, we're trying to help you.

Comment: Expecting member declaration

Comment: Are you just writing on the top level of a file or just inside a class? You should put your code in a function if it isn't in one. Can you post your code with more context?

Comment: is there any other way, I can Create a directory in android using kotlin

Comment: I have wrote it as a function also but then too the directory is not created

Comment: Are you having a compiler error, or a runtime error.  Your mention in a comment of "_Expecting member declaration_" is a compiler error, but your question sounds like it just doesn't work at runtime.  This should be clarified.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This works perfectly on Kotlin

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    var filename = "blesson.txt"
    // create a File object for the parent directory
    val wallpaperDirectory = File("/sdcard/Wallpaper/")
    // have the object build the directory structure, if needed.
    wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs()
    // create a File object for the output file
    val outputFile = File(wallpaperDirectory, filename)
    // now attach the OutputStream to the file object, instead of a String representation
    try {
      val fos = FileOutputStream(outputFile)
    } catch (e: FileNotFoundException) {
      e.printStackTrace()
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: What is it that makes this work, when the question didn't?  They look pretty similar - is it the extra slash?

Answer (score 5):

You can also use `also` to do this:

```
File("path_to_file").also {
                              file -> file.parentFile.mkdirs()
                          }.writeBytes(bytes)
```

Comment: [apply](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/scope-functions.html#apply) would be more concise:
`File("path_to_file").apply {parentFile.mkdirs()}.writeBytes(bytes)`